# How to Convert RDD[String,String] to JSON using GSON in Scala

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, gson

I am using `GSON` to convert `RDD[String, String]` where the value (2nd String) can be a case class with `Maps` and `Lists`. When I used `Gson.toJson` it gives to empty jsons like this :

```
 {"itemIds":{},"itemsNames":{}}
```

but I want :

```
{"itemIds":{"ABC" : 3,"123" : 33 },"itemsNames":{"ABC" : 3, "A" : 4}}
```

I tried with GSON :

```
  val gson: Gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create()
  def toJson(value: Any): String = {
     gson.toJson(value)
  }

 def getPersonRDD(result: DataFrame): RDD[(String, String)] = {

    val finalValue = result.rdd.map({
      r =>
        val customerId = r.getAs[String](CUSTOMER_ID)
        val itemId = r.getAs[Map[String, Int]](ITEM_ID)
        val itemName = r.getAs[Map[String, Int]](ITEM_NAME)


        val person = Person(itemId, itemName)

        val jsonString = toJson(person)

        (customerId, jsonString)

    })

    return finalValue
  }

  case class Person(itemId: Map[String, Int], itemNames: Map[String, Int]) extends Serializable
```

This gives me :

```
{"itemIds":{},"itemsNames":{}}
```

Tried playJson but getting error :

```
   trait JsonParser {
  def toJsonString(scenario: Person): String
}

     @SerialVersionUID(114L)
        class JsonParserImpl() extends JsonParser with Serializable {


          implicit val implicitPersonsWrites = new Writes[Person] {
            def writes(person: Person): JsValue = {
              Json.obj(
                "itemId" -> person.itemId,
                "itemNames" -> person.itemNames
              )
            }
          }

          def toJsonString(testDocument: Person): String = Json.toJson(testDocument).toString

        }

      def getPersonRDD(result: DataFrame): RDD[(String, String)] = {

            val jsonParserImpl = new JsonParserImpl
            val finalValue = result.rdd.map({
              r =>
                val customerId = r.getAs[String](CUSTOMER_ID)
                val itemId = r.getAs[Map[String, Int]](ITEM_ID)
                val itemName = r.getAs[Map[String, Int]](ITEM_NAME)


                val person = Person(itemId, itemName)

                val jsonString = jsonParserImpl.toJsonString(person)

                (customerId, jsonString)

            })

            return finalValue
          }
```

This gives me  :

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
    [junit] java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
    [junit]     at 
[
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here ? I am new to scala/spark. Please advise me on how to achieve this.

Comment: If I had to guess, `Any` does not define fields... Therefore, you are mapping to an empty object. In any case, please add the Spark code... This is just Scala

Comment: @cricket_007 Updated.

Comment: If you want case classes to be converted to JSON, you should try to use  json4s instead, as it is more geared towards Scala usage https://github.com/json4s/json4s#serialization

Comment: looking at your code suggests that you are converting dataframe to rdd and rdd to json using gson library. Thats too complicated. Why don't you take benefit from inbuilt functions as struct and to_json . Thats all. Simple